# Google Sheets: Using "match" with a variable starting point

Tags: google-sheets, match

I'm new to using the "match" function. I have a list of URLs that I'm importing using the "importxml" function. In doing so, some of my cells are blank or don't contain data that I need. The data that I need seems to shift around on occasion. For instance, it may start in cell A135 one day and then shift to cell A139 another day. Once I find the first cell then I know that I need the next 100 cells. I've got all of that figured out.
=match("*/football/players*",A1:A,0)+1
This gets me the row of where my data starts. For example, it returns a value of "135" to cell B1

Here's where I'm stuck: Once I get the first 100 entries then there's another gap of variable length and then another list of 100 entries. I need something like:
=match("*/football/players*",A&(B1):A,0)+B1

This, obviously, doesn't work. I'm stuck on how to handle the "A&(B1)" part. I may need to use something completely different.

I think I need to somehow use the "INDIRECT" function, but I'm not sure how to write the syntax.

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out where your data is, wouldn't it be better to figure out why you have the gaps, and/or remove them to make the data contiguous?

Comment: The "indirect("A"&b1&":a")" comment did the trick.  I can't fix the non-contiguous data issue because it's not my web page that I'm accessing.